# How to get message id in queue after call web-service in wso 2 esb

Tags: web-services, wso2-esb

I am using wso2ESB Version 4.9.0
I have a problem. My proxy like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="InOnlyProxy"
       transports="http,https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                      name="MESSAGE_ID_BOFORE"
                      expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
         </log>
         <store messageStore="s2"/>
        </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>


<messageProcessor name="Processor2" class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" targetEndpoint="EndPoint1" messageStore="s2" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="client.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">4</parameter>
   <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">replySequence</parameter>
   <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Disabled</parameter>
   <parameter name="member.count">1</parameter>
</messageProcessor>  


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="replySequence" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="REPLY" value="MESSAGE"/>
    </log>
   <send/>
</sequence>
```

Suppose my web-service has a message_id parameter and when i call this web-service with message_id=10, the web-service return same message_id with 10.

So now i call web-service without message_id.
I want save a message in  a queue and a messageProcessor call message in the queue. So i want a ID for identity message in replaySequence. I use message ID but  message id before call is different after call. so can you help me for identity message response?

I want call another web-service  in replaySequence using Message-id.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try setting up the property MESSAGE_ID_BOFORE outside the log mediator? If you want to log the message id, you can as in https://github.com/pubudu538/product-apim/blob/0de6a671d4985404493c0f6c875173e4a766459e/modules/distribution/resources/customsequences/in/debug_in_flow.xml#L15

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that i can use property in another sequence.